# Unable to preview Story

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-stream-story

I have a app in which I created a custom object with custom properties. The object is called "character" and the custom properties are theme (as string) and user (as profile).

I have an action called "vote" which contains a property "character" that references the custom object above.

I created a story that links the action to the object. All the flexible sentences refer to "character.title".

This was working fine for awhile and whenever I published a story I was able to see a preview of it in the story settings. Now I get an error [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q2sf.png)

I can publish using graph api explorer with no problems. And if I debug a character URL using the debugger tool, there are no errors. Everything looks good, but I can't see a preview and I'm worried that my published stories are not actually posting.

Another strange thing is that I have another app that I use for staging and testing purposes that doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had to click on Edit Attachments in the Story settings and set values for at least one of the fields. I guess without it Facebook didn't know how to render the preview. There should be an appropriate warning message.

Note: my other apps have been working fine without having to fill values in the Edit Attachments window. This app was a strange exception.

Comment: I had that exact same error, no idea why it happened. Thanks for posting this!